# Wrong Inference with Interfaces and Intersection Types in Typescript (strict Mode)

Tags: typescript

I have encountered a weird behavior with interfaces and intersection types in Typescript with `strictNullChecks` enabled. I have broken down my original code to a minimal generic (standalone) snippet (if you want to fiddle around, make sure to enable `strictNullChecks`), which you can find below. I have also included some alternative lines that, when used in place of the line above, make the snippet compile without errors. The error I get in this snippet is also included below.

```typescript
type FooOptions<OptionsT> = OptionsT & BaseOptions<OptionsT>;

interface Breaker<OptionsT>
{ (this: Foo<OptionsT>): void; }

interface BaseOptions<OptionsT>
{ breaker?: Breaker<OptionsT>; }
// {} // works! [A]

class Foo<OptionsT>
{
    public constructor(
        protected readonly options: FooOptions<OptionsT>,
    )
    {}
}

interface SpecialOptions
{ limit?: number; }
// { limit: number | undefined; } // works! [B]

interface BarFoo extends Foo<SpecialOptions> {}
type BarFooType = Foo<SpecialOptions>;

class FooFactory
{
    public bar(limit?: number):
        BarFoo
        // BarFooType // works! [C]
        // Foo<SpecialOptions> // works! [D]
    { return new Foo({limit}); } // ERROR comes from here
    // { return new Foo(<SpecialOptions>{limit}); } // works! [E]
}
```

The error received is the following. I have added newlines so you don't need to scroll horizontally.

```
Type 'Foo<{ limit: number | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'BarFoo'. Types of
property 'options' are incompatible. Type 'FooOptions<{ limit: number | undefined; }>' is not
assignable to type 'FooOptions<SpecialOptions>'. Type
'FooOptions<{ limit: number | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type
'BaseOptions<SpecialOptions>'. Types of property 'breaker' are incompatible. Type
'Breaker<{ limit: number | undefined; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type
'Breaker<SpecialOptions> | undefined'. Type 'Breaker<{ limit: number | undefined; }>' is not
assignable to type 'Breaker<SpecialOptions> | undefined'. Type
'Breaker<{ limit: number | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type
'Breaker<SpecialOptions>'. Type 'SpecialOptions' is not assignable to type
'{ limit: number | undefined; }'. Property 'limit' is optional in type 'SpecialOptions' but
required in type '{ limit: number | undefined; }'.
```

Comments on the alternatives:

- `[A]` No valid alternative. I need that thing. (Trivia: In my original code this is named `Breaker` as well. Who could know it would literally *break* my code?)
- `[B]` This would make leaving `limit` out impossible.
- `[C]` This is the alternative I will be using for now.
- `[D]` Is just [C] inlined.
- `[E]` If it doesn't fit, typecast it. I'm not a fan of this. I'd rather have the types inferred.

My question is: **Why doesn't it work? Or is this a bug? Or can/should I improve/correct somehow the `Breaker`/`BaseOptions` typing? If so, how?**

---

### Edit 1

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "lib": [
      "ES2017"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your settings. I'm trying to reproduce with strict null checks enabled, but I get no errors.

Comment: @Fenton Sorry, I just (falsely) assumed `strictNullChecks` is the important setting for reproduction. I added my `tsconfig.json`. Also I'm using *Atom* with *atom-typescript* 12.4.1. It should be using Typescript 2.8.3.

Comment: I am having real trouble teasing apart all the type juggling going on in that code.  It does look like it might be a bug or design limitation, but I can't be sure.  Ideally you would pare it down to the minimum reproduction so someone could debug it.    The workaround I'd suggest looks like `const f: Foo<SpecialOptions> = new Foo({limit}); return f;`, which is more type safe than assertions.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I get the sense that it the bug is that the intermediate `BarFooType` *does not* result in an error.  It looks like you've got the generic in a contravariant position (the `this` parameter on the optional `breaker` function) and therefore the compiler balks at the assignment, but somehow the intermediate assignment to `BarFooType` fools it.

Comment: The minimum reproduction I could come up with [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/354a954d96cb68ab90089a3a2e14fad2).  Not sure if it's worth finding or filing an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about it.